# Proposed edit by other user - reject or approve?

Tags: support, specific-question, review, editing

There is a (good) [pending edit](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31825) to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48854/other-than-trados) but I have not approved because the [editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/9311/michael-nancarrow) and the [OP](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/37209/mat) look like different users.

- They currently have 1010 and 1 rep respectively, so it could be that the question was quickly posted by someone making a proper (other) account later, but the question history on other SE sites points against that.
- Not much help from the [question timeline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/48854/timeline)

Questions:

- Do I reject the edit as *conflicts with the author's intent* or approve it?
- Is there other information available that can help making this decision?

Comment: That question was asked by the 1rep user and edited by the 1010er. I've seen it yesterday and haven't approved it either, with the reason that the owner should approve it if it matches his intent. I also left a comment pointing out the question misses essential details. So if OP is even too lazy to accept the edit, I don't see why we should put energy into it.